# Centering button using grid() in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am simply trying to center some buttons in Python and it won't work even after looking at other a dozen threads.

This is my code at the moment:

```
import tkinter as tk

HEIGHT = 600
WIDTH = 1000

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#000A01')
frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

button0 = tk.Button(frame, text="LEFT", relief='flat', justify='center', bg='#000A01', fg='#00A010', padx='35', width='0', font=('Monofonto', 18))
button0.grid(row=0, column=0)
button1 = tk.Button(frame, text="CENTER", relief='flat', justify='center', bg='#000A01', fg='#00A010', padx='35', width='0', font=('Monofonto', 18))
button1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button2 = tk.Button(frame, text="RIGHT", relief='flat', justify='center', bg='#000A01', fg='#00A010', padx='35', width='0', font=('Monofonto', 18))
button2.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

this is the output

[outputofabovecode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdld5.png)

I want all buttons to be centered in the middle of the window and if I were to add more buttons in the same row it would add more to the center.

Comment: See the first example shown in the **Patterns** section of this [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20201113212426id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook//place.htm).

Comment: Is your goal for `frame` to fill the window, or to be a largely invisible container which can be used to center the buttons? Your question isn't clear since you say you want to use `place` to center the buttons but you're not using `place` on the buttons.

Comment: my bad thats just a brain muckup on my part I did mean to write grid.

I'm new to python as a language so I assume I just want an invisible container in which my buttons will be placed

Comment: Change `frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)` to `frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)`.

Comment: Please fix the "muckup" by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

To center a button using place:

`place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)`.

Comment: I have already tried this, I just get the error "name 'CENTER' is not defined" https://imgur.com/a/Eagr3yT

Comment: *update* I fixed it as I realized I need to use "anchor=tk.CENTER" as I imported it as tk however with grid I can use rows and columns to space them out, will place put them side by side automatically as if I was using columns? they seem to be overlapping when I do it that way